# Method Post not sending all data from Form Table

Tags: php, forms, post

I am trying to Submit data to a PHP but it is not all showing up.  I get the straightforward data but not the selected Drop Down List item that I pre-fill from a MySql Db.

"name" & "parish" come through, but not "description".

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<!--Get connect string-->

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP Form 1</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Property Details</h2>

<form method="post" action="../php/property.php">

<!--Property Name-->
      Property Name:
      <input type="text" name="name"><br>

<!--Property Type-->
    Property Type:
          <select>
                         <option value="description">House</option>
                         <option value="description">Condo</option>
                         <option value="description">Apartment</option>
                         <option value="description">Fractional</option>
                    </select>
    <br>
<!--Parish-->
    Parish:
      <select id="parish" name="parish">
            <option value="City of Hamilton">City of Hamilton</option>
            <option value="Devonshire">Devonshire</option>
  </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Post the rendered HTML please, not the PHP. Also, for description to come through you need to name your select description. E.g. `<select name="description">`. The way you have it now, your select, if it was named, would have every option with the value of "description". Instead of `<option value="description">
                <?php echo $row["description"];?>
            </option>` you probably want something like `<option value=<?php echo $row["description"];?>">
                <?php echo $row["description"];?>
            </option>` or something where each option has a distinct value

Comment: OK - so I placed the rendered code from chrome